# Rendering feature labels in mapnik

Tags: node.js, mapnik

I am trying to render a mapnik stylesheet but nothing I try will render the labels.  Here is my stylesheet:

```
<Map srs="+init=epsg:4326">
  <Style name="Polygon">
    <Rule>
      <LineSymbolizer stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
      <TextSymbolizer face-name="DejaVu Sans" placement="interior" allow-overlap="true">[name]</TextSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
  </Style>
  <Layer name="polygon" srs="+init=epsg:4326">
    <StyleName>Polygon</StyleName>
    <Datasource>
      <Parameter name="type">geojson</Parameter>
      <Parameter name="inline"><![CDATA[
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [[
          [18.6609649658203, -32.59028569040753],
          [18.6536693572998, -32.59762547484460],
          [18.6737108230590, -32.59892704873228],
          [18.6609649658203, -32.59028569040753]
        ]],
        "type": "Polygon"
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "polygon"
      }
    }
  ]
}
      ]]>
      </Parameter>
    </Datasource>
  </Layer>
</Map>
```

The map itself renders fine, but I can't get a label to appear.  I am using `node-mapnik` which I've wrapped in a service inside a docker image, my code is [here](https://github.com/aquavitae/docker-mapnik).  I am loading the default fonts, and I have tried several variations on the syntax for `<TextSymbolizer>` but nothing makes any difference, the labels just don't appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else encountering this (because mapnik's docs are incomplete and in cases plain wrong) you need to load system fonts, not default fonts.  In the code:

```
const mapnik = require('mapnik');
mapnik.register_system_fonts();
```

Mapnik's example code for node shows `mapnik.register_default_fonts();`, but the folder that the fonts are supposed to be loaded from is empty and I can't see where they are supposed to come from.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set `placement-type` attribute? For example:

```
<TextSymbolizer face-name="DejaVu Sans" placement-type="simple" placement="interior" allow-overlap="true">[name]</TextSymbolizer>
```

Comment: Thanks. It actually ended up a an issue with fonts not being loaded.